# How come that conda commands do not show any output in Windows Powershell but in Anaconda PowerShell Prompt?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, anaconda, miniconda

Conda commands (as example here the --version command) do not show any output in PowerShell:

[image: Miniconda3 version checks in Windows PowerShell]

[image: Miniconda3 version checks in Anaconda Powershell Prompt (Miniconda3)]

The `$Env:Path` variable in Windows PowerShell contains the following conda-specific paths:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\Miniconda3;C:\PROGRA~1\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Miniconda3\Scripts
```

whereby `C:\PROGRA~1` is the short-cut name for `C:\Program Files`.
Whereas actually the Anaconda Command prompt *additionally contains* the following entries at the beginning of the `$Env:Path` variable:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\Miniconda3;C:\PROGRA~1\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Miniconda3\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\Miniconda3\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Miniconda3\condabin;
```

Now, I saw there is a slight difference, but when I add the Miniconda3 bin and condabin paths, it still does not work:

[image: Miniconda3 version checks in Windows PowerShell after adding Miniconda3 bin and condabin paths]

Does anyone have an explanation of this behaviour and on how I can resolve this? - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I checked on my old Anaconda Windows installation and it seems to be the same for me, so the problem may be with your Powershell. Try to update it and than check using:
`conda -- version` in Anaconda Power Shell and Build in.
For me `conda -- version` worked the same in all PowerShell versions.
Maybe it's PATH problem.Check PATH dependencies. If not helped try to re-install your conda.